# How to copy all files within a directory with globstar?

Tags: bash, shell, pattern-matching, glob, shopt

Say I want to copy all files within `dir` to `dest`:

```
$ tree .
.
├── dest
└── dir
    ├── dir
    │   ├── file1
    │   └── file2
    └── file3
```

This is easy if I know the filenames and the directory depths:

```
$ echo dir/f* dir/*/*
dir/file3 dir/dir/file1 dir/dir/file2

$ cp dir/f* dir/*/* dest/

$ tree dest/
dest/
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3
```

It's also easy (with globstar) to get only the directories:

```
$ echo dir/**/*/
dir/dir/
```

But I don't know how to **glob** only the files, e.g. the following doesn't work:

```
$ echo dir/**/*!(/)
dir/**/*!(/)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "only the files"? You want to exclude empty directories?

Comment: (AFAIK) you can't exclude all the directories with extended globs. A pattern like `*!(/)` doesn't work and `!(*/)` hangs the shell.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I want to *exclude* all directories, like `dir/f* dir/*/*` does.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `find` with `-type f` option:

```
find dir -type f -exec cp {} dest \;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. In the `-exec ... +` construct, the `{}` _must be the last argument of the command_. That's why some versions of `cp` come with the `-t` option: `find dir - type f -exec cp -t dest {} +`.

Comment: See the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html): _Only a plus sign that follows an argument containing the two characters "{}" shall punctuate the end of the primary expression. Other uses of the plus sign shall not be treated as special._

Comment: Thank you, but I'm aware of that. I'm interesting in **globbing**.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thanks for your comments, I learnt something new